# Metal MTLTexture replaces semi-transparent areas with black when alpha values that aren't 1 or 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, transparency, metal

While using [Apple's texture importer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MetalTexturedQuad/Listings/MetalTexturedQuad_AAPLTexture_mm.html), or my own, a white soft-edged circle drawn in software (with a transparent bg) or in Photoshop (saved as a PNG) when rendered will have its semi-transparent colors replaced with black when brought into Metal.

Below is a screen grab from Xcode's Metal debugger, you can see the texture before being sent to shaders.

[Image located here (I'm not high ranked enough to embed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGDI8.png)

In Xcode, finder, and when put into an UIImageView, the source texture does not have the ring. But somewhere along the UIImage -> CGContex -> MTLTexture process (I'm thinking specifically the MTLTexture part) the tranparent sections are darkened.

I've been banging my head against the wall changing everything I could for the past couple of days but I can't figure it out.

To be transparent (ha), here is my personal import code

```
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics

class MetalTexture {

    class func imageToTexture(imageNamed: String, device: MTLDevice) -> MTLTexture {
        let bytesPerPixel = 4
        let bitsPerComponent = 8

        var image = UIImage(named: imageNamed)!

        let width = Int(image.size.width)
        let height = Int(image.size.height)
        let bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height))

        var rowBytes = width * bytesPerPixel
        var colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

        let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, rowBytes, colorSpace, CGBitmapInfo(CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue))

        CGContextClearRect(context, bounds)
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, CGFloat(width), CGFloat(height))
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, -1.0, -1.0)
        CGContextDrawImage(context, bounds, image.CGImage)

        var texDescriptor = MTLTextureDescriptor.texture2DDescriptorWithPixelFormat(.RGBA8Unorm, width: width, height: height, mipmapped: false)

        var texture = device.newTextureWithDescriptor(texDescriptor)
        texture.label = imageNamed

        var pixelsData = CGBitmapContextGetData(context)

        var region = MTLRegionMake2D(0, 0, width, height)
        texture.replaceRegion(region, mipmapLevel: 0, withBytes: pixelsData, bytesPerRow: rowBytes)

        return texture
    }
}
```

But I don't think that's the problem (since it's a copy of Apple's in Swift, and I've used theirs instead with no differences).

Any leads at all would be super helpful.

Comment: That's not actually "black", you're seeing. It's white, multiplied by the alpha channel of the image, twice, with the background multiplied by the alpha's inverse and added to the result. I figured CGImageAlphaInfo.Last would solve the problem, but it isn't implemented on the hardware. Can you implement premultiplied alpha blending until we figure out how to get unpremultiplied data?

Comment: Aha! You led me along the right track. Posting my answer now.

Answer (score 10):

Since you are using a `CGContext` that is configured to use colors premultiplied with the alpha channel, using the standard `RGB = src.rgb * src.a + dst.rgb * (1-src.a)` will cause darkened areas because the `src.rgb` values are *premultiplied* with `src.a` already. This means that what you want is `src.rgb + dst.rgb * (1-src.a)` which is configured like this:

```
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].isBlendingEnabled = true
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .add
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .add
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .one
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .sourceAlpha
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
pipeline.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .oneMinusSourceAlpha
```

The `.one` means to leave RGB as-is. The reason for premultiplied colors is that you only need to multiply the colors once on creation as opposed to every time you blend. Your configuration achieves this too, but indirectly.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to Jessy I decided to look through how I was blending my alphas and I've figured it out. My texture still looks darkened in the GPU debugger, but in the actual app everything looks correct. I made my changes to my pipeline state descriptor, which you can see below.

```
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].blendingEnabled = true
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].rgbBlendOperation = .Add
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].alphaBlendOperation = .Add
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceRGBBlendFactor = .DestinationAlpha
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].sourceAlphaBlendFactor = .DestinationAlpha
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationRGBBlendFactor = .OneMinusSourceAlpha
pipelineStateDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].destinationAlphaBlendFactor = .OneMinusBlendAlpha
```